# Error In Uploading Profile Pic laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I'm currently using laravel, my error says

> image source not readable

I have used `$ php composer.phar require intervention/image`. It is installed successfully.

I have copied these for laravel integration

$providers:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

$aliases:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

my error :

```
    NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302:
    Image source not readable
```

my UserController file:

```
  if($request->hasFile('avatar')){

    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
                      Image::make('$avatar')->resize(300, 300)->save( 
    public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

  }

return redirect()->route('dashboard');

 }
```

my route file:

```
Route::post('/dashboard',[
                'uses'=>'UserController@update_avatar',

                ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `make()` part to this:

```
Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(....
```

Comment: i'm getting this error:
 NotWritableException in Image.php line 143: Can't write image data to path (C:\wamp64\www\Final Group\public\/uploads/avatars/1471074992.png)

Comment: when i change the file path to null,
 Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path(' ' . $filename) );
 the page is just refreshed the new pic is not uploaded..same default pic appears again

Comment: Change `public_path('/uploads/avatars/'. $filename)` to `public_path('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'avatars'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename)`. Also, since you use Windows, try to remove `read-only` flag from `uploads` folder recursively.

Comment: same error :

NotWritableException in Image.php line 143:
Can't write image data to path (C:\wamp64\www\Final Group\public\uploads\avatars\1471076825.png)

Comment: I guess you didn't change your code to mine, but merged them and now you got this: `\uploads/uploads/avatars/avatars/uploads/avatars/`. I can't see your current code, so I'm not able to help here, but it's really easy to fix.

Comment: What does `dd(public_path('uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'avatars'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));` show you if you put it right before `Image::make` clause? And `dd($filenamte);`?

Comment: on a blank white view

"C:\wamp64\www\Final Group\public\uploads\avatars\"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120857/discussion-between-vish-youtube-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: thanx .my images are saved in that folder ....but still only the default image appears on page ...it does not change